# Android-Jenkins: failed to find Build Tools revision 17.0.0 On Jenkins Build Server

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, ci-server

I'm trying to use the Android Emulator on Jenkins to build and test my project. But I'm getting an the following error when running my gradle tasks;

> failed to find Build Tools revision 17.0.0

the gradle task I'm running is;

```
./gradlew clean connectedCheck
```

in my gradle build file I has the following configuration

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 17
  buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 17
  }
}
```

The build server is a headless Ubuntu instance (12 something). My first thought was that I didn't have the correct build tools installed so I had a look in my android-sdk/build-tools director. All I could see was a directory called 18.1.1. So I thought if I updated my android sdk it would download version 17.0.0. So I ran the following command:

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```

and it seems to download various many things but looking in the build tools directory again I still only see version 18.1.1.

So questions are:

1) Am I right in assuming the build is failing because I don't have the correct build tools revision in my android sdk directory? (/android-sdk/build-tools)

2) How do I update the build-tools on a headless server so that I have version 17.0.0?

If you need me to provide more information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: try using `buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"` in your gradle build file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, `android update sdk` (or `android list sdk --extended`) only lists the packages which aren't considered deprecated.

As Build Tools 17.0.0 is a comparatively old version, it won't be shown by default.

Running with the `-a` (`--all`) flag will get you the older versions, e.g.:
`android update sdk -u -a -t build-tools-17.0.0`

---

At some point in the future the Jenkins plugin should automatically install the correct build tools for you, based on your build.gradle file.

---

**Edit (Nov 2015):** This functionality probably will not be added to the Android Emulator plugin.

Nowadays I would recommend using the [android-sdk-manager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin) Gradle plugin, which automates the installation of all prerequisites for a Jenkins build, including Android SDK, tools, build-tools, platforms, support libraries etc.

This can be very easily integrated into your project, and removes the need to keep the Android SDK installation on your Jenkins build machines up-to-date.

Comment: What do the -u and -t options mean?

Comment: @GabrielJiva You can check with `android update sdk --help`: `-u` performs the update on the command line without any GUI; `-t` filters the packages to be installed. In this case, only the build-tools component will be installed, rather than all available components.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do it, is manually update for the missing version using Android SDK Manager attached to Jenkins (Look for Configuration: ANDROID_SDK, then under it access "tools/android.sh")

[image]