# Unable to build soda-android-sdk

Tags: socrata, soda

I need help building the Socrata soda-android-sdk project. The project seems to be depending on some obsolete tools and does not build for me with the current Android SDK and related tools.

Following the README.md instructions, the failures start with

```
./gradlew connectedCheck --info
```

Running with the --debug option shows it failing with:

```
23:40:14.004 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:40:14.004 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':soda-android-sdk:compileReleaseAidl'.
23:40:14.005 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > failed to find Build Tools revision 17.0.0
```

The project has been dormant for a while. I'd be open to updating the project, and equally open to finding a binary distribution I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like asking a question to clarify the problem. After writing this up, I searched for "failed to find Build Tools revision 17.0.0" which lead me to this answer [about building Android Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19431623/1102502) with the wining recipe:

```
android update sdk -u -a -t build-tools-17.0.0
```

Might be good to update the soda-android-sdk README!